# How to restart the service in android once it stops because application restarts because of ANR error?

Tags: android, service

I am running a service in background in my android application. Sometimes the "Application Not Responding" error occurs and  if I select the "Force Close" option, the android kills my application and restarts it. In mean time the pid of my application changes to some new number. This error shuts down my service which is running in background. How can i restart the service in this case.

I am using Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler in my application. It catches all the other unhandled errors (and in those cases i restart my service from Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler block) but it does not catch the "ANR" error.

So how can i restart my service in that case?

Answer (score 1):

How do you start your service in the first place? Presumably your app starts it, so won't it just restart it when the app restarts?

Comment: I start my service with an activity called StartUp in this fashion: bindService(new Intent(this, UpdateService.class), mConnection,
    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);  But after the Force Close error the application does not start from first page but it restarts from that page where it got the Force Close error.